# Hyper-V management. RSAT or SCVMM?

Tags: hyper-v-server-2008-r2, scvmm

I have a relatively light duty Hyper-V server running 2 production servers and 3 dev servers. I've been using the [RSAT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc794756%28WS.10%29.aspx) with the Hyper-V role installed, and it seems to do just fine when it comes to managing the server's storage and VMs. I decided to setup a new machine and do some eval on [SCVMM](http://www.microsoft.com/systemcenter/virtualmachinemanager/en/us/default.aspx). Now that its up and running, I don't see any added value to it compared to RSAT on my Win7 box. Is it just not geared toward a small setup like mine, and really just meant for a much larger VM environment?

EDIT: Besides the ability to to P2V.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SCVMM is targeted at automating operations across many hosts.  A single host, or even a handful of hosts, won't be enough to see much difference.

And, by the way, if you're really dealing with only a few VMs, you'll probably get exactly what you want in P2V using disk2VHD.  See this:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ee656415.aspx

Just remember to change the storage driver set to include IDE/ATA before you take turn the disk into a VHD, or it won't boot within Hyper-V.

Comment: Disk2vhd is very cool but one other thing to note is that it's limited to disks < 127GB in size.

Comment: Actually, I think its VirtualPC thats limited to that disk size, not the utility.